# Finding the maximum average revenue

Tags: calculus

I have meet following question:
Find the maximum average revenue if the demand equation is $$P=500 + 10x - x^2$$

I know that average revenue is equal total revenue/number of item, so I have divided it by  $x$   and got 
$$P=\frac{500}{x}+10-x,$$
then I took the derivative  of this new given function and got $$\frac{\textrm{d}P}{\textrm{d}x}=-\frac{500}{x^2}-1.$$
But when I set it  to $0$ I get $x^2=-500$  which only has a complex solution. I was thinking that I dont need to divide it by $x$, just take simple derivative of given function, so that $\frac{\textrm{d}P}{\textrm{d}x}=10-2x$    set it zero  and get $x=5$,  then put into original equation and finally  I have got $500+50-25=525$, but I am not sure that it is right because they  asking me average revenue. Please help.

Comment: You're supposed to divide the total revenue by the number of items, but you divided $P$ by the number of items. $P$ isn't the total revenue, is it?

Comment: P   yes you are right is not total  revenue ,so i think that i should us formula R=P*x?(where R is total revenue, and P-demand function,x number of items)?

Comment: @user3196:  right.  Which means $P$ is the average revenue.

Comment: so as i concluded if i multiply demand  by x   get total revenue and then divide it by number of items to get avarage  revenue it means that demand is the same as avarage revenue yes?so just i should take  derivatives set it so zero and put critical point into my demand function?am i right?

Comment: @user 3196: You are right.

Comment: thanks very much @André Nicolas

Comment: The problem reminds me of the embarrassing fact that I once asked a very similar question on a test. Of course many people proceeded as you did, or maximized Revenue. It is not nice to fool people into doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Now that we know what the answer is, someone should post it as an answer, just to tidy things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $P$ is the average revenue, we can set the derivative $10-2x$ to zero and find $x=5$.  (posted as Gerry Myerson asked)